# FaceBook Share image set user edit disable

Tags: iphone, facebook, xcode4.5

my app that share image on Facebook. that work fine but i want to disable user inter face with post. So user can`t modify My initialText is this possible ?

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
                SLComposeViewController *fbComposer = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

                [fbComposer setInitialText:@"Yes U Are?"];

                if ([fbComposer addImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[Array objectAtIndex:i]]]) {
                }
                [self presentViewController:fbComposer animated:YES completion:nil];

            }else {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:@"Facebook Error"
                                          message:@"You may not have set up facebook service on your device or\n                                  You may not connected to internent.\nPlease check ..."
                                          delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alertView show];
            }
        }
```

hear is the image of Facebook share i want to only click on post btn And Cancle btn .So user can only Post.

[image]

Comment: i also stuck hear If u got Answer. It helpful for me Also Thanks for The Question

Comment: @ChiragCreative Oh that`s good. if u Got Any Solution please post your Answer. Thanks For Replay